# livedata of paging getOrAwaitValue make a test failed due to unfinished coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, android-paging-3

So, i want to test my livedata of paging on viewmodel that changing based on token mutablestateflow. Here is my `viewModel`

```
class MainViewModel(private val repository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val token = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val data: LiveData<PagingData<RemoteItems>> = token.switchMap {
        repository.getItems(it)
    }

    val refresh = repository.refresh

    fun getSession() = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getSession().collectLatest {
            token.value = it.token
        }
    }

    fun logout() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.logout()
        }
    }

    fun refreshed() {
        repository.refreshed()
    }
}
```

So, i make a test with robolectric and junit for this viewModel. Here is my test:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MainViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val executorRule: InstantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    val coroutineRule: MainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
    private lateinit var repository: UserRepository
    private val context = RuntimeEnvironment.getApplication().applicationContext

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        repository = UserRepository.getInstance(
            UserPreference.getInstance(context.dataStore),
            UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
        )
        viewModel = MainViewModel(repository)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Get Stories Success`() = runTest {
        repository.login("senjutsudimal@gmail.com", "gabbustacia")
        advanceUntilIdle()

        viewModel.getSession()

        val differ = AsyncPagingDataDiffer(
            StoryAdapter.DIFF,
            listUpdateCallback,
        )

        val token = repository.getSession().asLiveData().getOrAwaitValue(10).token
        val remote = ApiConfig.getApiService().getStories("Bearer $token", 1, 10)

        val pagingData = viewModel.story.getOrAwaitValue(100)
        differ.submitData(pagingData)
        Assert.assertNotNull(differ.snapshot())
    }
}
```

But the problem is, the test failed on differ.submitData due to coroutine didn't finished even after 10 Seconds. Why is that? I tried to create a fake list and insert into the differ, and everything works fine.

I already tried using another list and seems to work just fine, but when i want to test the paging itself, it doesn't works.